# how to make looping in the React state?

Tags: reactjs

I will make a loop a state in react, but is not as expected:

```
state={
  product:[
   {
     frontImage:"frontImage1.jpg",backImage:"backImage1.png"
   }, 
   {
     frontImage:"frontImage2.jpg",backImage:"backImage2.png"
   }
 ]
}
```

I try to use code like this

```
state = {
  product: this.props.location.state.colorPick.map(color => {
    frontImage:null,
    backImage:null
  })
};
```

but the results are like this:

```
{0: undefined1: undefined}
```

Comment: It would be helpful to know what `this.props` contains.

Comment: @Toto, try my solution below and let me know if that helps! :)

Comment: Just a tip: you don't use color parameter in your .map method, so it's useless. Use () instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use props to generate your desired output, an array of objects `[{...}]`

```
state = {
   product:[
      {frontImage:"frontImage1.jpg",backImage:"backImage1.png"}, 
      {frontImage:"frontImage2.jpg",backImage:"backImage2.png"}
   ]
}
```

Consider handling this logic in `componentDidMount()` instead. If you try to create the array during the state-initialization, its not a guarantee that the expected prop-values will be passed down before the component first renders. That's where `componentDidMount()` comes in, it executes logic **AFTER** the component has rendered once and we can expect `props` to be passed by then.

Try something like:

```
componentDidMount(){
  const newProduct = this.props.location.state.colorPick.map(() => {
     return {
         frontImage:null,
         backImage:null
     }
  })
}
```

Additionally, in your `.map()`, you are not using a short-hand, and you never explicitly called **return** so you would not get the desired object.